# bootstrap 4 form errors not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have have a bootstrap 4 form that's been through validation on the server (and generated an error) however the error doesn't show (but the red error border shows correctly), even though I can see what looks like valid html.

Using bootstrap 4 beta 2:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

(Hmm interestingly the error seems to appear as expected with bootstrap alpha 6 but not with beta or beta 2)

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="Xk3IX21aiZYwVaVXvM2dMLWfmhpb6idpeGvIH5RnfCPe2RRifuFA0ntUJRxC3Z7h"> <div id="div_id_postcode" class="form-group has-danger"> <label for="id_postcode" class="form-control-label sr-only requiredField">
                Please enter your postcode<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class=""> <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span> <input type="text" name="postcode" value="asdfasdf" placeholder="Postcode" autofocus="" class="textinput textInput form-control is-invalid" required="" id="id_postcode"> </div> <span id="error_1_id_postcode" class="invalid-feedback"><strong>Please enter a valid postcode</strong></span> </div> </div>

<input id="signup-submit" class="btn btn-block btn-cta-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bs4 beta bug (worked fine in alpha 6).

Bug can be tracked here.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23454